# Solaris JRE Mozilla

Tags: solaris, java, firefox

In an thin client setup where Solaris 10 is being used on client and server side. Java based web apps are opened in Mozilla web browser 1.7. JRE version 1.4.2.6 is installed for Mozilla.

On a few thin clients, it works fine. However, on opening multiple sessions, it gets stuck with a dull green window left and requires force quit.

Why does it behave like that?